# Apache POI - NullPointerException when reading an excel file

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, apache-poi, testng, data-driven-tests

I ran the following code and got the error mentioned below. It is basically trying to read from an excel file and then do a function.The function ReadExcelDemo outputs properly if i print, but when the values are taken to the other function, it throws this error. Something inside the second function throws the issue it seems. Any idea?

---

```
public class ReadExcelDemo
{
    public ArrayList readExcel()
    {
        ArrayList dataList = new ArrayList();
        FileInputStream file = null;
        try
        {
            file = new FileInputStream(new File("/tmp/DataSheet.xlsx"));

            //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            //Iterate through each rows one by one
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext())
            {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                //For each row, iterate through all the columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    //Check the cell type and format accordingly
                    switch (cell.getCellType())
                    {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                           // System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "t");
                            dataList.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                           // System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "t");
                            dataList.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            break;

                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            file.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.print(dataList);
        return dataList;

    }
}
```

---

```
public class LoginAttemps extends Setup {
    private String baseUrl; 
    public void testSearchCountry() throws Exception {
        baseUrl = "http://google.com";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        ReadExcelDemo readXls = new ReadExcelDemo();
        List dataList = readXls.readExcel();            
        for (int i = 1; i == dataList.size(); i++) {
            String[] test = (String[]) dataList.get(i);
            String countryName = test[0];
            String countryDesc = test[1];
            System.out.println(countryDesc);
        }
   }
}
```

---

I get an error,

```
FAILED: testSearchCountry
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.bobcares.webdriver.branding.Main.testSearchCountry(Main.java:46)
```

---

Any clue?

Comment: driver.get(baseUrl);
did U initiate it anywhere?? if no this is null. Also post your code fully. whit commen in line 46.

Comment: Thanks... That was an issue with the inheritance given.